# Creation date of the new account in an account merge

Tags: support, merge-accounts

What would the (login) name and creation date of the new account be? - the date of the oldest account, the other account, or the current date?

Comment: *Merges always go into the profile that has the lower user ID, and whatever display name, profile picture, and other information that is in use on that lower-ID profile is what gets kept after the merge unless that information hasn't been changed yet on that profile.* [found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305389/158100)  nothing on the date though.

Comment: _the profile that has the lower user ID_ – presumably that would always be the older account, then?

Comment: @Josh That's correct, I doubt it's possible for a newer account to have a lower user ID.